# How to use a SqlCommand Parameter to specify the schema name for a select query

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

The name of the Schema in our database is dynamic. Why won't the following work?

```
public void ReadVersion(string connString, string schemaName) 
{
    string selectCommand = "SELECT major FROM [@SchemaName].[version]");
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString)) 
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectCommand, sqlConn)) 
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchemaName", schemaName);
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

When the command is executed, the parameter value is not substituted. Is this a limitation of the SqlCommand Parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can't* do the following in plain SQL (so ignoring all of the ADO.Net overheads):

```
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
SET @SchemaName = 'dbo'
SELECT major FROM @SchemaName.[version]
```

And the reason is simple. What SQL wants after `FROM` is a *name*. What you're trying to give it is a *string*. SQL Server *doesn't* randomly start peering inside of strings to see if they resemble some other construct.

To your sanitation query, assuming that you're keeping the schema names sane, just use a simple regex on the schema name before you trust it (e.g. `^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+$` should be enough for most uses). Make sure you use a whitelist (allowed characters) rather than a blacklist.

Comment: Thanks Damien - my SQL understanding has grown. I now see that I can make our code a lot more elegant by giving the DB users (which query the schema at runtime) a DEFAULT_SCHEMA - because we create a matching unique DB user for each schema.

Comment: Hi - I hope I dont necro this thread, but is it viable to just check @SchemaName against sys.schemas to validate it ?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a limitation of the SqlCommand Parameters?

Yes, it is a limitation. In ADO.NET you cannot use parameters for the schema (things like table and column names). Your best bet is to use string concatenation and obviously as a result your own filtering for injection.

Comment: I think that this is not a limitation of SqlCommandParameter. They were not designed for such use in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I wanted to use parameters so that I don't have to worry about SQL injection. This public method is in a library to be used by other internal projects. Any advice on how to 'filter for injection'?

Comment: @GarethOwen, you may want to create a test that passed schema name is valid. For example the length and should not contain [,],",'.