# How do I specify a schema qualifier for a table in a C# SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Working code is of the form:

```
string sql = "SELECT foo from myTable";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
contractTable = new DataTable();
da.Fill(contractTable);
```

Now the database schema has been changed from dbo to mySchema, it's not my user's default 
schema, and I don't have admin rights to change it. When I try to run the code I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'myTable'.

OK, I understand, it's not finding it as it's not `dbo.` any more.

I tried adding the line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchemaName", 'mySchema');
```

but that had no observable effect.

Then based on [How to use a SqlCommand Parameter to specify the schema name for a select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094370/how-to-use-a-sqlcommand-parameter-to-specify-the-schema-name-for-a-select-query)

I tried adding the lines to my SQL

```
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
SET @SchemaName = 'mySchema'
SELECT foo FROM @SchemaName.[myTable]
```

but that gives me an invalid syntax error at the table name when executing the SQL SELECT

What's the correct syntax for this?

Comment: @Math.....if your SQL is in your code, this should work: string sql = "SELECT foo from " + aSchema + ".myTable";  But it does have the danger of SQL Injection

Comment: What's wrong  with `"SELECT foo FROM mySchema.myTable"`? Or do you mean that the schema name itself is a parameter?

Comment: you can use stored procedure and pass schema name as parameter and use your @SchemaName sysname queries in SP. This way you don't have to worry about dynamic sql and any injections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SQL is indeed your code, this should work:

```
string aSchema = "newSchema";
string sql = "SELECT foo from " + aSchema + ".myTable";
```

But it does have the danger of SQL Injection

Additionally, you could put the schema name in your config file and reference the config entry in your C# code.  This would protect you in the future in the event that the schema changes again.

```
string aSchema = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("schema_name");
string sql = "SELECT foo from " + aSchema + ".myTable";
```

Comment: Thanks yes that works but I greatly simplified the problem. I now have to go through many SQL statements adding the qualifier in multiple places. It's a shame I can't just set the default schema.

Comment: You could always use IF OBJECT_ID('Schema.Table') . . . or something similar to check the schemaName and tableName parameters against injected SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The schema qualifier is one of the items that cannot be specified with a variable (much like column and table names).

You will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for this - constructing the SQL and executing it.

This comes with its own dangers ([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) being primary).

The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL is an article by Erland Sommarskog that discusses and explains the different issues at length.

Comment: Fascinating no doubt but I need a quick fix here.

Comment: @TheMathemagician - All the answers you will get are essentially the same thing.